# How to avoid duplicate counts in column A while also checking if columns A and B meet a criteria

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns. Column A and B.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | Orange |
| Sarah | Apple, Orange |
| Sarah | Apple, Orange |
| Luke | Apple, Lemon |
| Jane | Apple |

Column A contains duplicates, 'Sarah' in this example, which I wish to keep included in the table.
I've been trying to count how many 'Apple' are in column B. While counting Sarah only once.

I'm really stuck here. I figured how to apply a formula but only for each cell individually.

How to count unique values for column A "=COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A2)" and how to count the apple in column B with "=COUNTIF(B1:B2, " * Apple * ")"

But I wasn't able to find any answers in regards to counting both column A and B after they meet their criteria.

The count should be 3 but I'm stuck with 4 instead.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: @Harun24HR solved it! Thank  you very much! I'll delete the sheet but I wanted to share a screenshot of the table and solution in case anyone needs it.
[Solution number one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0CP1.jpg)
[Solution number two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57uz7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `UNIQUE()` function like-

```
=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(A1:B5),"*Apple*")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! In the sheet I'm working on, there are another extra two columns; C and D. How can I count the values in A and D and exclude B and C?

Comment: You may share a sample sheet then explain what you expect.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I created a sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1soaG78T3sXvI1zIZatI6-xiK9hcbWnKohkO6rbCMBzY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function. Try- `=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(QUERY(A3:D8,"select A, D")),"*Apple*")`

Comment: Or `=COUNTIF(UNIQUE({A3:A8,D3:D8}),"*Apple*")`

Comment: If you found the answer helpful then you should accept the answer (tick mark it) so that other visitor can know it solve your problem.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, @Harun! I'm a noob so I spent hours searching for a solution. Thank you so much!